# Modified Bubble Sort's time complexity

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, sorting, arrays

I have an array (of hundreds of numbers) and I need to sort them. In this case, I used Bubble Sort because of the better time complexity compared to other algorithms, $\Theta(n^2)$.

```
procedure bubbleSort(arr)
        for i=0 to n-i-1
            for j=0 to n-i-2
                if arr[j] > arr[j+1]
                    Swap arr[j] and arr[j+1]
                end if
            end for
        end for
end procedure
```

I tried a modified version of Bubble Sort, as below;

```
procedure bubbleSort(arr)
    flag = true
    for i= 0 to n-1 do
        for j=0 to n-1-i
            if leftElement > rightElement         
                swap leftElement and rightElement   
                flag = false
            if flag is true
                break
            end if
        end for
    end for
end procedure
```

So, adding a flag variable that is set true if a swap is made after an entire pass over the array. If no change has been made, then the list is sorted, so the algorithm can stop earlier.

But, after testing the sorting execution time, it turns out that the modified algorithm is slower in many cases.

****What am I doing wrong or what am I not understanding?****

Comment: How is `for i=0 to n-i-1` well defined in the first procedure? How are `leftElement` and `rightElement` defined in the second procedure?

Comment: Also you say "I used Bubble Sort because of the better time complexity compared to other algorithms", but I [beg to differ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts).

Comment: @Nathaniel one of the best*, also because of the space complexity and tiny code size too

Comment: @Nathaniel `leftElement` closer to the 0 element of the array - than `rightElement`

Comment: What do you mean bubblesort is "one of the best"? Bubblesort is not great. It has constant number of comparisons on lists of identical size. Other algorithms such as quicksort, merge sort and heapsort have nlogn asymptotic average time

Comment: @Michel like I said, because of it's time and space complexity and it's tiny code size. And is the one I chose for my problem. Beside this, do you know what am I doing wrong in the modification?

Comment: How did you measure the time of these algorithms? The variant you mention is discussed in Knuth's TAOCP Vol 3, so you can check its static time analysis there

Comment: @Michel I measured the time using System.nanoTime() in Java (total nanoseconds from the start of the sortation till the end of the sortation)

Comment: Your question is too imprecise. What are your inputs? It seems from your comments that you use the algorithm in a specific application. If the inputs are not arbitrary lists, say a strict subset of the lists of size N then the time os affected. Also your comment on left element closer to zero needs to be put in the question. How do you know the list contains zero? You need to reformulate the question so readers have a chance to interpret matters correctly. How do you decide the element is closer to zero?

Comment: @Michel 0 element of the array meaning first element in the array. I thought it was obvious :). And yes, I stated in the first sentence that I am using the algorithm in a specific application: "I have an array (of hundreds of numbers) and I need to sort them"

Comment: "better time complexity": certainly not.

Comment: As written, your code is broken. The if/break is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bubble Sort's time complexity of $\Theta(n^2)$ is not good — it is a common worst-case complexity class for simple sorting algorithms that do not use divide & conquer methods to partition the dataset. These include eg. Selection Sort and Insertion Sort, each of which generally out-performs Bubble Sort due to making far fewer unoptimal swaps. Quicksort also is in this class in the worst case, but the average case is in the much less dramatically scaling $\Theta(n \log n)$ class.

Yves' answer explains why early termination can be a bad idea. However, if you want to preserve a fast termination for nearly-sorted data, I recommend switching to Insertion Sort which overall performs better than Bubble Sort and whose performance further improves substantially for nearly-sorted or sorted data without the need for additional checks. Insertion Sort is commonly used as an optimization for standard library sorting algorithms to process small enough (sub-)arrays to be sorted due to being very performant on smaller datasets, responding well to partially-sorted inputs and being stable (it does not modify the relative order of equal-valued inputs).

Answer (score 2):

Early termination can be a bad idea. Because if the condition for early termination is not met, you perform the whole processing plus testing the extra condition for nothing on every iteration.

The same holds with search in a binary tree: most implementation test for equality of the key to perform early termination. But it is easy to show that significantly early termination is so rare that on average the test is penalizing.